# eclipse like word completion in VS

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, autocomplete

Does VS have the option or do you know of a plugin that 
has the same "Complete Word" functionality as found in Eclipse (originates from VIM).
Talking about Alt + / (default).
This is not intelli-gent in any ways, just scans for words with the same first letters up and down.

Comment: What's wrong with intellisense? It always gives me sensible completions.

Comment: doesn't work when editing html/css/javascript
otherwise it's awesome, perfect for c#

Comment: Visual Assist ( http://www.wholetomato.com ) will do some Complete Word functionality in html and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Control + Space in VS2005/VS2008 when Intellisense is on and indexing was successful (automatically done by Intellisense). Of course, you can change the hotkey. Try Visual Assist plug-in for earlier versions.

Comment: that's a bit different. it's great for typed languages but when editing raw text files, INI files etc... it won't help at all.